# What is the difference betweens the Rogue Talent Lethal Acrobatics and the "Scout" Rogue Archetype's Scout's Charge?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, class-feature, rogue, conditions, flat-footed

What is the difference betweens the Rogue Talent Lethal Acrobatics and the "Scout" Rogue Archetype's Scout's Charge?

> **Lethal Acrobatics (Ex)**: When a rogue with this talent successfully uses Acrobatics to move through an opponent’s square without provoking an attack of opportunity, that opponent is considered flat-footed to the rogue’s next attack until the end of the rogue’s turn.
>
> **Scout’s Charge (Ex)**: At 4th level, whenever a scout makes a charge, her attack deals sneak attack damage as if the target were flat-footed. Foes with uncanny dodge are immune to this ability.

Aren't these moves similar and achieve the same result or am I missing something?

Comment: I'm not seeing any similarity between these two abilities, what makes you think they are similar?

Comment: I am unclear as to why this question is downvoted. While the difference may be clear to me and someone with knowledge of the system, a brand new player who doesn't understand mechanics may ask what seems to us as a simple question..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference between these two abilities is quite simple, and quite fundamental. While they both result in allowing you to sneak attack, the action that proceeds that attack is different.

**Lethal Acrobatics** requires an acrobatics check made as part of a move action. Theoretically, this can be done if the rogue is already next to that opponent.

The **Scout's Charge** requires a charge. Meaning the rogue must be at least 10 feet away from the enemy you are charging.